# Facebook Twitter Sharing options in app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I want to give sharing option in my app for sharing data, images, webpages, etc. with Facebook, Twitter, Email. What is best option for me?

I'm going through [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) that I have never used. Is it any good or do I have to try something else?

Suggest me some ShareKit like links.

Answer (score 2):

ShareKit is brilliant.

Recently there's been an intermittent problem with Facebook's "Connect" API, which is what ShareKit uses. A lot of existing, deployed apps (including some big names) have been facebook-broken over the last couple weeks. Facebook claims to be working on it, and in fact my app that uses ShareKit IS working right now, but ultimately SK needs to move to the newer Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Sharekit is good idea to share data,urls and images(not to twitter) with Facebook,twitter and Email but you can't share images in Twitter.